# Bitwise Operator in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, bitwise-operators

I have 8 viewController Objects `(vieController1, viewController2,...viewController8)` and 4 type of relationship `(move_up, move_down, move_left, move_right)`.

Each controller have some relationship with other controller.

For Example:

viewController1 and viewController2 have relationship between them `"MOVE_UP"` and `"MOVE_DOWN"`
viewController1 and viewController3 have relationship between them `"MOVE_RIGHT"` and "`MOVE_LEFT".`

So, i am thinking, can i store all the relatives controllers are in 8 bit format.
Example:
if `viewController1` relatives are `viewController2, viewController4, viewController5` and `viewController8` means

```
viewController1 relatives = 011011000.
```

same for all the controller.

and the same way can i store all the relationship with each controller in 4 bit format.

Example:
if `viewController1` relative `viewController3` and the relationship between them `move_up` and `move_down`

`viewController1 relatives = 00100000` and `relationship = 1100.`

This is better way to store or there is any other way in Objective c. if this is better way means kindly guide me to go forward. other wise give ur suggestion regarding this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it is a good way of doing it. Simple and fast.
Is there something that becomes completed by using your approach in Objective-C? 
My personal belief is that you can use as much C you want, it is after all a subset of C :-)

Comment: Seems like a good approach.  Offhand I can't think of any Objective-C facilities that would do the job better, especially if you're comfortable with the bit manipulation.  However, were it to get much more complex you might want to look into NSSet/NSMutableSet.

Answer (score 0):

Only one thing I noticed was that the relationship between the controllers should follow the binary order, just for clarification.

i.e. 
`viewController1` relative `viewController2, viewController4, viewController5` and `viewController8` is shown as

```
      viewController1 relative = 10011010
```

Edit:
For clarification

`viewController2 has bitmask = 00000010`

`viewController4 has bitmask = 00001000`

`viewController5 has bitmask = 00010000`

`viewController8 has bitmask = 10000000`

and `and`ing them together gives the relationship for the `viewController1`.

Comment: Sorry I accidentally removed you post...
Can you repost it?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I did not mean to disrespect.
I did not "fix" the code in the question actually, just reformatted it.
The OP counted the viewControllers from left to right in his post, and I think for clarification it should be counted from right to left.
What I changed in the OP's post was that there were too many numbers in the       viewController1 relative = 10011010        there should only be eight numbers.

Comment: thank you for ur ans. but how can i store this format in objective see. can u explain which data type is suitable for this and how can i parse while fetching each relative controller.